# Can't run eclipse project imported from Bazaar

Tags: eclipse, bazaar

I'm trying to run a project imported from Bazaar repository. I wasn't able to make it work, there is some message "The selection cannot be launched, and there is no recent launches". Any workaround on this?

Comment: Check you running configuration (menu in the "run" button)

Comment: I tried that, but when I browse for my project, the project isn't there.

Comment: Just to be sure, what do you mean by 'imported from Bazaar repository' ? Have you done a simple checkout/branch from a bzr repo on your lcoal drive, and then open the project from Eclipse ?

Comment: What kind of project is it?  Were the .project and other dot files stored there as well?  If not, what did you do to recreate them locally?

Comment: I pull them from the git repository. then I import them in my workspace. If I import them separately (I have two projects, one of which is ddependent on the other), there are gazillions of errors I'm not quite sure how to fix but if I import them as a whole there are no errors at all

Comment: only problem is I can't run it.